# null pointer exception in spinner adapter

Tags: android

i am trying to use this adapter on spinner , which is giving null pointer exception ,
kindly give ur worthy responses

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, R.array.select_action_arrays);
```

and in my string.xml file

```
<string-array name="select_action_arrays">
        <item>alert1</item>
        <item>alert2</item>
        <item>alert3</item>
        <item>alert4</item>
        <item>alert5</item>
    </string-array>
```

here is the complete code line

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.select_action_arrays));
        spinnerSelectAction.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinnerSelectAction = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerSelectAction);
        spinnerSelectAction.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinnerSelectAction.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            int count=0;
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                if(count >= 1){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"inside on item selected ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                count++;
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {}
        });
```

the spinnerSelectAction seems to be initialised

Comment: Post the code surrounding that line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't seem to initialize your adapter correctly. It should be something like:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
     android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
     getResources().getStringArray(R.array.select_action_arrays));
```

Comment: nope still the same error in 
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
     android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
     getResources().getStringArray(R.array.select_action_arrays));
spinnerSelectAction.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: the exception is coming in
spinnerSelectAction.setAdapter(adapter);
this line , the very next line , i tried to debug , the adapter shows some id , means its not null

Comment: So then spinnerSelectAction is null?

Comment: Yeah. And, as requested before, the surrounding code, where you initialize the things that could be null...

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid Your spinnerSelectAction view probably is null. Check it once again.

Comment: oops found it , thanx for your help frnz , yeah the spinneralert action is NULL , thanx u guys again

Answer (score 1):

Write below code line

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.select_action_arrays));
```

instead of

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, R.array.select_action_arrays);
```

may be it will solve your problem.

Comment: Probably, this will not answer the question. Please make it a comment.

Answer (score 0):

you are adding to adapter before retrieving the spinner from the view, the 2 first instructions should be like that :

```
spinnerSelectAction = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerSelectAction);
spinnerSelectAction.setAdapter(adapter);
```